# Is algorithm analysis needed for a linux kernel, linux device driver or module writer programmer?

Tags: linux, algorithm, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am not good in analysis of algorithm and trying to get some knowledge.
As I am interested in kernel, linux device driver or module writer programming is this analysis really needed for these programming ,if yes then some concept is enough or I  have to be good analyser of my code or Can I skip this and work on Programming knowledge like C,C++,Linux kernel etc

Thanks

Comment: I am learning ,even I do not know what are the types of driver so I want to start.

Comment: Any significant programming task involves being able to gauge the scalability of your solution, and that's why you study algorithm analysis.  For kernel code, scalability issues could crash the host, so it's hard to imagine a situation where you could completely ignore these things and still do useful work in kernel space.

Comment: Thanks triplee,for your information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Programming without algorithms is like literature without sentences -- it is a non-sensical idea.  Every block of code you write implements some algorithm, it doesn't make sense to set out to write code without understanding algorithms.

Happily for you, one of the best ways of achieving understanding of algorithms is to implement algorithms.

Which algorithms you need to be intimate with, and which aspects of their analysis, is, once you get beyond the basics (sorting, searching, basic data structure manipulation), domain specific.  So you should direct your research, once you have mastered the basics, towards your chosen domain.

Answer (score 1):

For being a Linux kernel programmer,

You should have some knowledge in the following areas.

```
Operating system Concepts(Memory Management, Process Management particularly)

Good C programming.

Based on Driver you working, you should specialize the kernel APIs. 

Basic hardware knowledge like BAR, Interrupt, Register.
```